# JS Regexp different from Regex online tester

Tags: javascript, regex

The Regex below works fine in Regex101 for my purpose, but for some reasons I have a different results when using the highlight-within-textarea Jquery plugin.

Regex101 results: https://regex101.com/r/K1WT05/2
Regex: `(?<![\w-])(excel|technology|technology-based|c#|software & framework|\.net)(?![\w-])`

Here is the results from JSdiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/seb_london/wm9yqazj/4/

As you can see, the keyword "excel" is still highlighted in "BIexcel" and in "excellent".

So my question is, how can I make sure that "excel" doesn't get highlighted in "BIexcel" and in "excellent"?

Comment: If you log the `pattern` variable form the code you can see that in the pattern  `(?<![w-])(excel|technology|technology-based|c#|software & framework|.net)(?![w-])` the backslashes are missing. Try double escaping them.

Comment: ok great thanks for your help. It needs two backslashes instead of one before the w i.e. (?<![\\w-])

Answer (score 0):

I needed two backslashes before the "w" as mentioned by The fourth bird user.

So instead of this:

```
(?<![\w-])(excel|technology|technology-based|c#|software & framework|.net)(?![\w-])
```

I needed this:

```
(?<![\\w-])(excel|technology|technology-based|c#|software & framework|.net)(?![\\w-])
```